# Why can I not scroll past my parallax without moving the mouse first?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scrollbar

So I am trying to do a Webpage with a Parallax landing picture. For the Parallax effect to work, it has a higher height, so the user will have to scroll down. This creates a second scrollbar on the side only for this Parallax. So far so good. The problem is when I scroll down to the end of the Parallax, the second scrollbar is not activated automatically, I have to move the mouse a little bit to continue scrolling on the normal content of the Webpage. 
Here is a working example of my problem:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ckuessner/pen/rNxBWvj)

Is there any way I can make it keep scrolling after reaching the end of the Parallax without moving the mouse first?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #fedcc8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: #2d112b;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="parallax">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <v-col class="pa-5" cols="12" md="6">
    <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
              scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
              porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
              scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
              porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
              scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
              porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
              scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
              porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </span>
    <span class="d-flex justify-center">
              Skills
            </span>

    <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte tur adipi scin e<br />
              lit. Etiam vulputate augu e vel felis gravida porta.
            </span>
    <v-row>

    </v-row>
  </v-col>
</section>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, I would suggest adding a `position: relative;` in the `.parallax` in order to [remove the double scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/rgkLqjhb/3/).

The issue you're experiencing is a browser related scrolling issue and not a problem with your code (it does work on Firefox, but not on Chrome for example). So there's no "fix".

But there's clearly other ways to go about using parallax to prevent the issue from even happening like scroll each parallax manually without relying on browser's scroll.

Or you can simulate a click when reaching the top or the bottom to be able to overcome the issue :

```
$('div').on('scroll', chk_scroll);

function chk_scroll(e) {
  var elem = $(e.currentTarget);

  if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
    $("#parallax").trigger("click");
  } else if (elem.scrollTop() == 0) {
    $("#parallax").trigger("click");
  }
}
```

```js
$('div').on('scroll', chk_scroll);

function chk_scroll(e) {
  var elem = $(e.currentTarget);

  if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
    $("#parallax").trigger("click");
  } else if (elem.scrollTop() == 0) {
    $("#parallax").trigger("click");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #fedcc8;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: #2d112b;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section id="parallax">
  <div style="height: 100vh">
    <div class="parallax">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__cover"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <v-col class="pa-5" cols="12" md="6">
    <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
      scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
      porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
      scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
      porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
      scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
      porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
      scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
      porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
    <span class="d-flex justify-center">
      Skills
    </span>

    <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte tur adipi scin e<br />
      lit. Etiam vulputate augu e vel felis gravida porta.
    </span>
    <v-row>

    </v-row>
  </v-col>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have two scrollbars, the behaviour you described is **intended**. You can't change this behaviour. What you can do is to alter your solution so that it conforms to the intended behaviour (i.e. make one scrollbar appear only instead of two).

You're using `perspective` and `translateZ` to create the parallax effect. This means that the container of the "parallax-ed" items must have the `perspective` property and the items themselves must be a **direct descendent** of the container. In the solution below, we're setting the `perspective` attribute to the `body` element. This means that the parallax only occurs when the `body` element is scrolled. Without configuring the `overflow` of the `html` element, the scroll will appear on the `html` element; thus, it is essential to set the `html` element's `overflow` attribute to `hidden`. This will cause the scrollbar to appear on the `body` element.

My answer is very similar to [Dennis Ranish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62248334/9060223). **However,** I use `background-image` and `background-position: center bottom` to make it so that the image is automatically centered regardless of its width (in your solution, you used `margin-left: -1500px` to do this). Using this solution, you **need not** know the intrinsic size (original size) of the image and the image will always be centered even if you change the image later on. This is more flexible than using fixed units. Coincidentally, this requires me to use `div`s and this works in your favour (because you mentioned a problem of using `img` directly in Vue [do take a look further to see what the underlying problem exactly is; it might not simply be caused by the `div`]).

Furthermore, I used `top: 100%` and `position: relative` to adjust it so that the content is located directly below the image. Here's the solution.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #fedcc8;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
}

div[class^="parallax__layer"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  background-position-x: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.parallax__content {
  background: #2d112b;
  top: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 200px 100px;
}

.parallax__layer--zero {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer--one {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer--two {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer--three {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer--four {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer--five {
  background: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer--six {
  background-image: url('https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true');
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class='parallax__layer--zero'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--one'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--two'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--three'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--four'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--five'></div>
<div class='parallax__layer--six'></div>
<div class='parallax__content'>
  <h1>Hello y'all, this parallax works!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly this is probably a slightly better method. I did notice you have a slight gap on the right (at least on my computer). This is cause the perspective origin is in the very center regardless of the scroll bar. Since scroll bars are different sizes on different devices the translateX(-6px) wouldn't always be correct. I did figure out you can fix this by removing the translateX(-6px), and setting parallax__layer width to 100vw instead of 100%.

Comment: @DennisRanish Right, thanks for the tip, I couldn't figure out why I needed to `translate` by a few pixels (i.e. what caused the `div` to move slightly to the left on my screen).

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is not a problem. Your example has 2 different elements that have a scroll bar, one with-in the other. For-example if you look at one of the code snippets on this page you will experience the same behavior. This is intended. When you reach the bottom of an element you typically don't want to start scrolling the main page all of a sudden. Chrome for example waits for you to do another action like move the mouse or just pause for long enough, then it lets you scroll the parent element.

---

For the parallax effect you do not want multiple scroll-able elements; you only need one. Additionally you do not need all those extra divs. Here is how I would do it...

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fedcc8;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
}

img {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(-1500px + 50vw);
  border-top: calc(100vh - 455px) solid transparent;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  background: #2d112b;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 25px);
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 2px);
  padding: 25px;
}

.text-box {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #fedcc8;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  font: italic small-caps bold 16px/2 cursive
}

.parallax-0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax-4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax-5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax-6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<img class='parallax-0' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true'/>
<img class='parallax-1' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true'/>
<img class='parallax-2' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true' />
<img class='parallax-3' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true'/>
<img class='parallax-4' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true'/>
<img class='parallax-5' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true'/>
<img class='parallax-6' src='https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true'/>
<div class='content'>
  <div class='text-box'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida porta. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

First thing is set the body's perspective so that there is parallax. Also it is important to set the html overflow to hidden because by default page scroll bars belong the the html element. Then for the elements that get the parallax effect it is important to make sure that get moved/scaled correctly to properly align. By default all the transformations happen based off the center point. You choose to put the images inside divs that are the size of the screen and align the images to the bottom, which works well. For simplicity in the example the images are given a top border to be the size of the screen but still be at the bottom. They are also centered, z-index set to -1 to be behind the rest of the page, and their bottom is set to 0 to handle very wide screens correctly (when the border is negative it does nothing). Finally there is a div which contains the rest of the page. It has a top margin of the screens height to allow room for the parallax mountains (I subtracted 2px because I notices a weird gap between it and the mountains on mobile).

If you want to have the mountains start somewhere higher up you can put them inside of divs like you have and align them at any height or if you don't want to add divs you can do it like this...

```
/*__img__*/
border-top: calc(45vh - 455px / 2) solid transparent;
border-bottom: calc(55vh - 455px / 2) solid transparent;

/*__.content__*/
margin-top: min(100vh - 2px, 100vh + 455px / 2 - 2px);
```

---

The important thing to take away from this example is that you have to have the scrolling only happen in one element. Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks quite good, unfortunately if I put this in my vue component, it doesn't show the images anymore, I have not yet figured out why that is.

Comment: If I remove the divs around the <img> tags the pictures are no longer shown, any idea what that's about?

Comment: You could always put the surrounding divs back if you can't figure it out. I don't really know too much about vue, seem like a weird issue. Be sure to check the style with dev tools or something, maybe vue effected the styling slightly (again don't really know too much about vue.)

Answer (score -1):

This code have nice scrolling. I have refereed this [link](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) to redo your code. Hope it helps.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fedcc8;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 100%;
  perspective-origin-x: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

.cover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2d112b;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.cover2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fedcc8;
}

.parallax__group {
  height: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin-x: 100%;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  z-index: 5;
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  z-index: 6;
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<section class="parallax__group">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
    <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
  </div>
</section>
<section class="parallax__group cover">
  <v-row>
    <v-col class="pa-5" cols="12" md="6">
      <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
      <span class="d-flex justify-center">
     Skills
    </span>
      <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte tur adipi scin e<br />
     lit. Etiam vulputate augu e vel felis gravida porta.
    </span>
      <v-row>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</section>
<section class="cover2">
  <v-row>
    <v-col class="pa-5" cols="12" md="6">
      <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi<br />
     scin elit. Etiam vulputate augue vel felis gravida<br />
     porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </span>
      <span class="d-flex justify-center">
     Skills
    </span>
      <span class="d-flex justify-center mb-5">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecte tur adipi scin e<br />
     lit. Etiam vulputate augu e vel felis gravida porta.
    </span>
      <v-row>
      </v-row>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</section>
```

Comment: This looked good at first, but sadly it just works because everything is inside one component, when I implement this into my webpage there are still two scrollbars and it doesnt keep scrolling after reaching the end of the page :/

Comment: Then it is not a generic case. This must be specific to your platform, Vue js right? I never used Vue. But I have a intuition that some js script/css is altering the DOM after it is loaded. This will create some awful looking effects like you see there. One way to debug is the compare what is changing inside your browser with above code. There must be something difference. That will help you fix it. Other than that, I can not help you without you whole code including all dependencies you are using.

Comment: I don't think that VueJs is the problem here, your code simply contains one big component. I have other components underneith it, so different sections. And it doesn't keep scrolling on those sections. So I would have to put everything inside one component to make it work like that which would destroy everything vue stands for :D

Comment: if its possible can you share vue code using scrimba.com link?? I think I can fix it without breaking much rules.

Comment: Because its very critical to know how you are planning to using parallax elements as components.

Comment: @Ckuessner alright. Try it now.I edited my answer. Made the css little dirty. xD. But it works great now with vue.

Comment: Your code as is doesn't have the parallax effect like at all.

Comment: hmm. You are correct. But It was working on my pc. i'll check out where it went wrong.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy The code is fixed. It was some unknown bug. Because the code in my pc worked fine and I just copied it again to my answer. I hope this solves this.

Comment: Not yet, the problem is that your demo only has one scrollbar, so all of your page can scrolled with that one bar, I will test it this evening but I doubt that it will work with my parallax

Comment: Thats how usually all websites works. Maybe i am not able to understand what you need exactly.